# I don't understand why string.size returns what it does

Tags: ruby, heredoc

```
long_string = <<EOS
It was the best of times,
It was the worst of times.
EOS
```

that returns 53. Why? The whitespace counts? Even still. how do we get 53?

How about this?

```
     def test_flexible_quotes_can_handle_multiple_lines
    long_string = %{
It was the best of times,
It was the worst of times.
}
    assert_equal 54, long_string.size
  end

  def test_here_documents_can_also_handle_multiple_lines
    long_string = <<EOS
It was the best of times,
It was the worst of times.
EOS
    assert_equal 53, long_string.size
  end
```

Is this the case because the %{ case counts each `/n` as one character and theres considered to be one before the first line, one at the end, and then at the end of the 2nd line, whereas in the `EOS` case theres just one before the 1st line and one after the 1st line? In other words, why is the former 54 and the latter 53?

Comment: Oh please not Charles Dickens quotes...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For:

```
long_string = <<EOS
It was the best of times,
It was the worst of times.
EOS

String is:
"It was the best of times,\nIt was the worst of times.\n"

It was the best of times, => 25
<newline> => 1
It was the worst of times. => 26
<newline> => 1
Total = 25 + 1 + 26 + 1 = 53
```

And

```
long_string = %{
It was the best of times,
It was the worst of times.
}

String is:
"\nIt was the best of times,\nIt was the worst of times.\n"
#Note leading "\n"
```

**How it works:**

In the case of `<<EOS`, the lines that follow it are part of the string. All the text after `<<` on the same line as `<<` and to the end of the line would be part of the "marker" that determines when the string ends (in this case an `EOS` on a line by itself is matching the `<<EOS`).

In case of `%{...}`, it is just a different delimiter used in place of `"..."`. So when you have the string starting on a new line after a `%{`, that newline is part of the string.

Try this example and you will see how `%{...}` is working same as `"..."`:

```
a = "
It was the best of times,
It was the worst of times.
"
a.length # => 54

b = "It was the best of times,
It was the worst of times.
"
b.length # => 53
```